# Can Eclipse respect JAVA_HOME or path environment variable order?

Tags: eclipse

In order to change the VM used by Ecipse, I have to change eclipse.ini, which is not convenient, because I have manually edit the file whenever I download a new copy. It's a pain if you have several machines to deploy.

Seems eclipse does not respect JAVA_HOME or path environment variable order. Etc,

1. It cannot load the JVM specified by JAVA_HOME.
2. It cannot load the JVM which is the first java.exe under path environment variable.

Is there workaround to make Eclipse to respect JAVA_HOME or path environment variable order?
Or does Eclipse.exe accept some parameter to allow it to specify the JVM when it starts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Eclipse does not respect `JAVA_HOME` environment variable which is mentioned as the follows from [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM):

> If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use
> it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the
> system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME
> environment variable.

But it does provide command line argument `-vm` to directly specify a JVM to run it. Different OS has the own value format , refer [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_macOS_Example) for more details.

So in case of the MacOS , you can execute something like the follows to directly configure a JVM to start Eclipse :

```sh
eclipse -vm $JAVA_HOME/bin
```